# How can I make HashSet operations to be O(n)?

Tags: java, hashset

How can I make HashSet operations to be O(n)?

It has the standard collection operations Add, Remove, Contains, but since it uses a hash-based implementation, these operation are O(1).

But when are operations O(n)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to know? And what interest is there in making things slower than what they normally are?

Comment: why would you want to worsen its performance from O(1) to O(n)?

Comment: Operations, in general, are O(n) when the worse case leads to traversal of all the existing elements. So, inserting the largest number into a an already ascending ordered list. However to ponder this for a hashed structure, considering it would be contrary to the whole point, is pretty pointless. The only realistic answer is to have either a poorly sized table or a crappy hash function.

Comment: I wonder why you guys speak about `worsening` - `Big-O` notation describes an upper bound. So the operations of every reasonably implemented HashSet are in `O(n^k)` for `k>=0`:)

Comment: @cel, wouldn't you agree that the question comes from the idea of a not reasonably implemented HashSet?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, no I don't think so. But I like the answers saying that a degenerated `hash` function can make all operations work in `o(n)`. Making the implementation of an algorithm worse is not that difficult :)

Answer (score 7):

One pathological case that would lead to O(n) behaviour is when all elements have the same hash code.

Comment: Beat me to it! `@Override public final int hashCode() { return 42; /* universal answer, and random */ }`

Answer (score 1):

If you hash function (your hash generating function itself) will produce a hash key in O(n) complexity then all your operations would be in this complexity.

Comment: Producing a Hash key *should be* independent of `n`. It is about how unique the key is that affects the search and in-turn the *performance*.

Comment: @TheLostMind Producing a hash key is not necessary a constant(at least, one can deliberately make it `O(n)`).

Comment: the question itself (I think) is some kind of "curiosity thinking" - so there is no reasoning to do hash function in this kind of complexity

Comment: @user2040251 - It makes little sense to make hash code generation dependent on number of elements.

Comment: For that to work, the element's `hashCode()` would somehow need to know the size of the set the element is in. The mechanism for achieving that is unclear.

Comment: @NPE you are right! we can provide this length number to the function.

Comment: @NPE - Though Java certainly doesn't restrict *how* hash code should be generated, but does it make sense to make hash code generation *dependent* on n?

Comment: @TheLostMind: I take it the question is rhetorical. :)

Answer (score 1):

NPE is mostly correct.

However, I should add that in Java 8, `HashMap` and `HashSet` were improved to replace long hash chains with binary trees in the case where the key type implements `Comparable`.  (See [JEP-180](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180))

This means that the pathological case of `O(N)` operations only happens when all elements have the same hashcode *AND* the key type *doesn't* implement `Comparable`.  If the key type implements `Comparable` then the worst case complexity of `get` on a `HashMap` or `HashSet` is `O(logN)`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this without overriding a class (as NPE does) is to create lots of keys with the same hash code. e.g.

```
Set<Long> longs = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    Long element = ((long) i << 32) + (i & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
    assert element.hashCode() == 0;
    longs.add(element);
}
```